# Installing alongside formats other swap partitions

Tags: system-installation, swap

Why does the installer, when installing a new system along side other installations, warn that it will be formatting the other existing swap partitions ?

Is it safe to confirm this dialog? Will it affect the other swap in any away rendering them unusable by the other systems?

Comment: You only need one swap partition for all installations. Having more then one is a waist of disk space. ...and yes, formatting a swap partition will likely make it unusable.

Comment: As above. You can, during the subsequent distro installation, select "something else..." and explicitly mark the current `swap` for use without formatting.